# Plot_ly stacked barchart messes up y axis

Tags: r, plotly, yaxis

I'm trying to plot a stacked bar chart in plot_ly, but I run into an odd problem. Plot_ly somehow squeezes the y-axis labels into the bottom left corner, while plotting the bar chart correctly. Here is a reproducible example:

```
x <- "Test"
y <- c("03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00",
       "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00",
       "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "24:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00")
df <- data.frame(x, y)

plot_ly(df, x = x, y = ~y, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

In my viewer pane that produces the following plot:
[image]

And as you can see in the bottom left corner, thats where all labels are "hiding".

**Question:**
How do I get the y-axis realigned with the values of y, so that it displays over the whole size of the plot?

Comment: Your sample code raises the error `Error in data.frame(x, seq) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it. Any ideas though how my initial problem could be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the y-axis realigned with the values of y, so that it
>   displays over the whole size of the plot?

That depends a little on what more you'd like to do with the rest of the plot.

Maybe setting `layout(barmode = "overlay")` will suffice?

**Plot1:**

[image]

Let me know if this does not solve your challenges!

Comment: Unfortunately not. Yours is a great idea, however now I am missing the vertical lines within the plot, like in my original graph. Any ideas?

Comment: @YannikSuhre Some ideas. And some challlenges. I'll take a closer look in a bit.

Comment: @YannikSuhre Could you share a bit more details about what you'd like to do here? In this case, all `y` observations are associated with that one single `x`. What does the rest of the data structure look like?

Comment: That is hard to explain. What my initial idea was, was to make some kind of video magazine. I have data for the start and end time of TV shows and I tried to make some kind of overview, so that you could see when which show started and when it ended in the course of a day. Any ideas on how to realize that? Maybe another plot form, apart from a stacked bar chart?